# Delphi TDataSetProvider.ApplyUpdates how to use

Tags: delphi, dbexpress

I cannot figure out which parameter to pass to TDataSetProvider.ApplyUpdates
The definition says:
function ApplyUpdates(const Delta: OleVariant; MaxErrors: Integer;  out ErrorCount: Integer): OleVariant;

What should I pass to the parameter Delta? I cannot find any example in the delphi documentation.
I am usign dbexpress and I want to call ApplyUpdates to apply the changes made to the records to the database.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Assigning_Data_Directly) will help.

Comment: Thanks, I used the ClientDataSet.Delta as parameter and it worked. I do not know if you should post it as an answer

Comment: No, just delete the question again.

Comment: ?? The question is a valid question and I do not delete it.

Comment: Fair enough, but I was just doing a quick google search. Perhaps one of the Delphi regulars will come along and post a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the provider and the clientdataset are connected (by setting the provider property of the CDS), changes are applied by

```
CDS.ApplyUpdates(0);
```